# Can I specify the components of FourVector in FeynCalc?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm using FeynCalc to calculate Compton's scattering. I need to use specific values for the components of the photon polarization four-vector. How can I do that?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the use of FeynCalc is sufficiently esoteric that (a) you may not get anyone here able to help and (b) might be better asking this question of the package's publishers.

Comment: go to mathematica.stackexchange.com, but you need to elaborate on the specific problem you are having

Answer (score -1):

I am going to give a short answer here, for more details, see my answer on Mathematica StackExchange:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161767/can-i-specify-the-components-of-fourvector-in-feyncalc/204639#204639

So, one can define the two functions

```
Mink[t1_, t2_] := 
  t1[[1]] t2[[1]] - t1[[2]] t2[[2]] - t1[[3]] t2[[3]] - 
   t1[[4]] t2[[4]];
LevContracted[a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
 Sum[-LeviCivitaTensor[
      4][[mu, nu, alpha, beta]]] a[[mu]] b[[nu]] c[[alpha]] d[[beta]], {mu, 1, 4}, {nu, 1, 4}, {alpha, 1, 
   4}, {beta, 1, 4}];
```

and define vectors as lists, e.g.

```
p = {x, y, z, w};
```

in order to calculate **fully contracted amplitudes**. Here, I am working with the signature (+---). The additional minus sign in the second function arises from the convention that ɛ​^{0123}=+1 and our vectors are taken to be contravariant.